# Reverse tabs using css3

Tags: css, tabs

I am using trapezoid style tabs but I want to modify this tab by vertically flipping the tab. Details are given below.

**Existing design**
[image]

Here is the code for this tab.

```css
.tabs-style-tzoid nav ul li a {
  padding: 0 1.5em 0 0.3em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}

.tabs-style-tzoid nav ul li a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  background: #1CA4FC;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  content: '';
  -webkit-transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(0.93deg) translateZ(-1px);
  transform: perspective(5px) rotateX(0.93deg) translateZ(-1px);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs tabs-style-tzoid">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="tab-current">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span>Messages</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="# "><i class="fa fa-check "></i><span>Applied Jobs</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="# "><i class="fa fa-mail-reply "></i><span>Past Jobs</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><span>My Profile</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i><span>Resume</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i><span>Document</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i><span>Settings</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

How can I make tabs look like this image.

**desire image**
[image]

Thank you community for helping me.

Comment: Link for current design https://tympanus.net/Development/TabStylesInspiration/

Comment: @young-kyun-jin thank you for editing my question. do you have any solution for this problem?

Comment: You should add HTML code..

Comment: @young-kyun-jin can you check now please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this:

```
.tabs-style-tzoid nav ul li a::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    background: #2CC185;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    content: '';
    -webkit-transform: skew(-28deg) rotateX(0.93deg) translateZ(-1px);
    transform: skew(-28deg) rotateX(0.93deg) translateZ(-1px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.tabs nav a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 2.5;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

if you try this css over the web that you post, it works fine.
the changes i made are:

to `.tabs-style-tzoid nav ul li a::after`

```
border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
-webkit-transform: skew(-28deg) rotateX(0.93deg) translateZ(-1px);
transform: skew(-28deg) rotateX(0.93deg) translateZ(-1px);
```

to `.tabs nav a` i add:

```
border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
```

Comment: Thank you @leonardo-cabré just what I was looking for.